# Datatables plugin Loading json Data error from web service(.net)

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I'm trying to use DataTables (getting data from Ajax) on my website form. 
I was experiencing some difficulties with that so I took a step back and tried to implement DataTables on a very basic table.

But I'm failing to get Datatables to work even on this basic table. What am I missing?  :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_id_example1').DataTable({
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxTest.asmx/HelloWorld",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            //dataSrc: "" ,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                alert(json.d);
            },
        },
        "columns": [
            { title: "ID"},
            { title: "Name"},
            { title: "Email"},
            { title: "Extension"}
        ],
    });
})
```

when the page loads, Datatables always shows "Loading".

Then I added

```
success: function (json) {
    alert(json.d);
```

This alerts the following:

> [{"id":1,"Name":"Jack","Email":"jack@test.com","Extension":"1001"},{"id":2,"Name":"Mike","Email":"mike@test.com","Extension":"1002"},{"id":3,"Name":"Rose","Email":"rose@test.com","Extension":"1003"}]

It that returned json string correct? Or are my Datatables params settings wrong?

Comment: Can you try to create snippet first? may be you will get your mistake on your own.

Comment: Thanks trincot, I'm newbie of stackflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add success callback in datatables ajax, just bind your columns with appropriates keys like,

```
$('#table_id_example1').DataTable({
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": {
         url: "AjaxTest.asmx/HelloWorld",
         dataSrc: "d" , // add data source, in your case it is d
     },
     "columns": [
        { title: "ID",data:'d.id'}, /// bind data with their keys
        { title: "Name",data:'d.Name'},
        { title: "Email",data:'d.Email'},
        { title: "Extension",data:'d.Extension'}
     ],
});
```

Please refer [ajax-configuration](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Ajax-configuration) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
this time , page shows different error.   `DataTables warning: table id=table_id_example1 - Requested unknown parameter 'd.id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: In your json response it is `id` or `Id`, remember the capital `I`, or just try `'d.Id'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any search parameters at the moment, simply specify the url for data loaduing following way:

```
 "ajax": {
           "url": "AjaxTest.asmx/HelloWorld"
         },
```

instead of your's one:

```
"ajax": {
        type: "POST",
        url: "AjaxTest.asmx/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        //dataSrc: "" ,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json.d);
        },
```

I had written posts on using the datatables with server side paging, searching which you can find in following location:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170086/Grid-with-Server-Side-Advanced-Search-using-JQuery

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/Grid-View-with-AJAX-based-CRUD-Operations-in-ASP-N

Answer (score 0):

thanks all.
It works after converting json.d to js object

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#table_id_example1').DataTable({
                "processing": false,
                "serverSide": false,
                "ajax": {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxTest.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    ////data: {},
                    dataSrc: function (json) { return $.parseJSON(json.d); },
                    //success: function (json) {
                    //    alert(json.d);
                    //    //alert(JSON.stringify(json.d))
                    //}
                    //},
                },
                "columns": [
                { title: "ID",data:"id"},
                { title: "Name", data: "Name" },
                { title: "Email", data: "Email" },
                { title: "Extension", data: "Extension" }
                ],
            });
        })
```